# Getting iOS password AutoFill to work with a "change password" page

Tags: ios, xcode, ios11, keychain, ios12

I've gotten iOS password autofill to work with "login" and "new account" pages but not a "change password" page. I have 4 UITextFields on that page. 1 with .email as the content type, 1 with .password as the content type for the original password, and 2 with .newPassword as the content type for the new password.

The autofill tries to fill in the .password and first .newPassword fields with a new generated password and the last field is blank. I've tried switching the order but then the password doesn't get updated in keychain.

I tried only having the 2 .newPassword fields but it still doesn't update they keychain.

Does anyone know how to get it to work or if there is a tutorial on a best practice for "change password" screens? Apples documentation only covers login and new account.

thanks.

Comment: Entirely unrelated, how did you get the .newPassword and autofill to work?

Comment: Hey, I'm facing exactly the same issue... Did you manage to solve it?

Answer (score 7):

I experience the same problem: AutoFill fills old password and new password field with the same generated password.

I solved this by moving the old password field up above the username.

- Current password (content type: `password`)
- Username (content type: username) (in my case this is a non editable pre-filled text field)
- New password (content type: `newPassword`)

It's a bit strange but after the view controller dismisses the keychain password is updated immediately without confirmation.

Comment: This only sort of works for me. It give me the correct field filling behavior (mostly; sometimes it doesn't draw the strong password in the new password fields), but it's not reliable about saving the changed password to the keychain. It seems like I need to fill in the current password before autofilling the new password. If I autofill the new password, then fill in the current password it doesn't save the new password to the keychain.